# Create Custom Membership Provider (Entity Framework vs Linq)

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm starting work on a Custom Membership provider and I was wondering which option would be the best to develop this application in Linq or Entity Framework?

Also I have a need to link two table from different database via a common ID and I was wondering does anyone know of any good tutorials about creating a MVC 3 Web Application that uses either Linq or Entity Framework to do this.

From my research Entity Framework seems to be the best method suited to my situation but I would appreciate some advice / confirmation that this correct and a little direction to a tutorial is possible?

Comment: Ideally, a membership provider should be persistent ignorant, meaning it shouldnt really know whether its using Linq, EF or stored procedures for that matter. All that aside, my vote would be for EF code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Linq, you mean Linq to SQL vs. Entity framework? If so, then I would recommend using Entity Framework. Microsoft's development on Linq to SQL has virtually stopped so EF has a better future.

NerdDinner is one of the more popular tutorial applications that uses ASP MVC 2 and entity framework. ASP MVC 2 is similar enough to get started with the basic concepts. Here is a good walk through tutorial:

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

The code itself is freely available:
http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks I've been through the nerd dinner stuff before. I thought EF was the way to proceed but I just need someone else to confirm my thoughts. Every new project I'm always sketchy and doubting myself as I don't want to make the wrong decision in the early stages.